# Function returning TCHAR * type vector doesn't return it correctly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The function below doesn't return vector correctly because if I want to use some element of this array in the other function it's always **-->** ` **<--**. Maybe I'm returning the vector incorrectly? I commented the lines which cause problem.

```
vector< TCHAR* > GetListOfModules( HANDLE proc )
{
    HMODULE hMods[ 1024 ];
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    vector< TCHAR * > ListOfNames;
    if( EnumProcessModules( proc, hMods, sizeof( hMods ), &cbNeeded ) )


 {
        for ( int i = 0; i < ( cbNeeded / sizeof( HMODULE ) ); i++ )
        {

            TCHAR szModName[ MAX_PATH ];
            if ( GetModuleFileNameEx(proc, hMods[ i ], szModName,
                                      sizeof( szModName ) / sizeof( TCHAR )) )
            {
                char * ptr = strrchr( szModName,'\\' );
                if( ptr != NULL )
                    strcpy( szModName, ptr+1 );
                ListOfNames.push_back( ( TCHAR * )szModName );
                //cout << ListOfNames[ i ] << endl; // it works
            }
        }
    }
    return ListOfNames;
}

void main()
{

    vector < TCHAR * > test;
    test = GetListOfModules( GetHandleByName( "explorer.exe" ) );
    //cout << test[1]; // it doesn't work
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/1553090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing pointers to a variable that is local to the for loop. It seems to work the first time because you are in the same iteration but really this is just lucky. Returning a pointer or a reference to a scope local variable is not something you can do in C++. You should either dynamically allocate the TCHAR* array and store unique_ptr in the vector or use strings instead.

`TCHAR szModName[ MAX_PATH ];`

This variable here gets overwritter at every iteration.

P.S: void main is non-standard, please use int main.

Comment: `return 0` is not needed for `main` in C++. Falling off the end of `main` is equivalent to an implicit `return 0`.

Comment: @celtschk I still prefer to return something, but it's true that it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: It would be worth being explicit about the fact that you are *not allowed* to return a pointer to the locally-scoped variable, rather than suggesting that it "works the first time".  It doesn't work at all.  If it seems to work, it's just a co-incidence.